# Reorder the data out put of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that produces data for call center solution. However, is there a way to modify the sp so that each time the data is executed it is delivered in a different order? For Example Today: 1,2,3 Tomorrow: 2,1,3 the next day 3,1,2 . Is there a manipulation I can execute that will scramble the order whenever it is executed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes simples.
    ORDER BY NewID()

Answer (score 1):

SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY NewID()